# Swaping Images in ViewController from two Arrays

Tags: ios, arrays, oop, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview

I am new to programming in Objective C, and I am trying to make two arrays with different pictures, and update a single `UIImageView`. When the user taps on the `ImageView`, I want the Images to swap.

The Error I am getting is:

```
"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI size]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8ccfbe0'"
```

*ViewController.m*

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ImageStore.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    ImageStore *imageStore = [[ImageStore alloc] init];

    if ([_imageView isHighlighted]) {
        self.imageView.image = [[imageStore backImage] objectAtIndex: 0];
    }

    else
    {
        self.imageView.image = [[imageStore frontImage] objectAtIndex: 0];
    }

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

*ImageStore.h*

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ImageStore : NSObject
{
    NSArray *frontImage;
    NSArray *backImage;
}


@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *frontImage;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *backImage;

@end
```

*ImageStore.m*

```
#import "imageStore.h"

@implementation ImageStore

@synthesize frontImage, backImage;

-(NSArray *)frontImage
{
    if(!frontImage) frontImage = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@[@"Icon.png", @"OtherIcon.png"], nil];
    return frontImage;
}

-(NSArray *)backImage
{
    if(!backImage) backImage = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@[@"OtherIcon.png", @"Icon.png"], nil];
    return backImage;
}


@end
```

The reason I am using an array is, I intend to place this in a `CollectionView`, however I can't seem to get the model correct even at this level. So I am taking this one step at a time.

Perhaps there is a better way to do this?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful with your code

```
self.imageView.image/*UIImage*/ = [[imageStore backImage] objectAtIndex: 0]/*NSString*/;
```

Your 2 array `backImage`, `frontImage` is arrays of **`NSString`** objects.

`self.imageView.image` is a property of **`UIImage`**

You can NOT set `UIImage` to `NSString`

You should change ImageStore.m

```
#import "imageStore.h"
...........
...........
-(NSArray *)frontImage
{
    if(!frontImage)
    frontImage = @[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"OtherIcon.png"] ];
    return frontImage;
}

-(NSArray *)backImage
{
    if(!backImage)
    backImage = @[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"OtherIcon.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon.png"] ];
    return backImage;
}
............
............
@end
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me understand what @[@""] actually does!

Comment: Never mind. You can try `@YES` `@NO` `@(123)` `@{@"key":@"value"}`